# Storing books in the Arcaneum library

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I store books that I no longer need in the Arcaneum bookshelves (the ones that are unlocked), will those books still be there if I look for them later, or can they become lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arcaneum Library is not a ["Safe Location"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Safe), so storing things in the bookshelves here is not safe.  If the area [respawns](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawn), you'll lose any items you left there.

On top of that, there's a note on the [Containers page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Containers) about bookshelves in particular:

> Bookshelves can often glitch, causing you to lose any books that are stored on the shelf you are using. If you try to overload the shelf with too many books, you may permanently lose all the books on it, as well as making the shelf unable to be activated. Occasionally these books are still visible but unable to be activated. Also, the "take all" button will sometimes only take some of the books, permanently deleting others.